# How do I install this file?

Tags: software-installation

Sorry guys, complete noob here, if it's not in the snap store I'm lost.

I downloaded Mari from https://www.foundry.com/products/mari/download

How do I safely install this?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

[image]

Comment: Where did the file come from and what is its extension? Can not tell anything from that picture.

Comment: Sorry yes the picture was bad, its a shell script

Comment: Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run

it came from that link I posted

Comment: Are you trying to run a program? All you are showing is the name of a script. Your link requires a login I will not do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.foundry.com/mari/content/getting_started_guide/installation_licensing/installation_linux.html). You can simply run:

```
chmod +x Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run
sudo ./Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run
```

You will then presented with EULA which prompt you to accept it.

---

The official docs pretty much cover everything you need to install → https://learn.foundry.com/mari/content/getting_started_guide/installation_licensing/installation_linux.html

Comment: I cd into that folder
sudo ./Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run
sudo: ./Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run: command not found

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just an idea, try this: `chmod +x Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run && sudo ./Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run`.

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'Mari4.7v4-linux-x86-release-64.run': No such file or directory

Comment: You need to `cd` to the folder where the `.run` file resided, then execute the command.

Comment: yes sorry, got it and it seems to be working, many thanks for your time